# How to increase width of children from the right to the left?

Tags: css

I have a toogle switch written in CSS. When you :active the switch handler, it increase it's width. From left to right its all good. But when the switch is on the right side and you :active it, it overflows it's parent.

So the question is, how to increase/decrease the width from right to left?

Comment: make a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: We will need to see the code in order to help you.

Comment: Code? U have to show the DOM and your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dock it on the right.

Many ways to position it:

1. `float: right;`
2. `position: absolute; right: 0;`

So, if it docks on the right and varies with width, it will stretch from right to left.